# Django templates _set.all two sub table

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have two tables I want to check if there is data or not!

Models:

```
class Children(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='avatar.jpg')
 
class Groups(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Children, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Templates:

```
{% if user.children_set.all.groups_set.all.exists %}
```

It's Like:

```
get_groups = Groups.objects.fitler(child__user=request.user).count
```

BUT I need this statement to be in templates, because I am trying to create for loop on User table:

```
{% for user in users %}
   {{user.username}}
   {% if user.children_set.all.groups_set.all.exists %}
      Yes
   {% else %}
      No
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use if condition in template if checking numbers is the ultimate goal like this:

```
{% if user.children_set.all.groups_set.count == 0 %}
   <p>this table is empty</p>
{% else %}
   <p>this table is not empty and go with the looping to print items etc<p> 
{% endif %}
```

this may help

Comment: It's not working, because it's a sub sub table